# Bought vs Have bought

Tags: present-perfect

I **bought** a new cell phone

I **have bought** a new cell phone

What is the difference?

Answer (score 4):

Grammatically, as I'm sure you know, the difference is that the first example is simple past, and the second is present perfect. The difference in meaning is minor, and the difference in usage (in the real world) is also quite minor.

If you want to be specific about the place or time that the event occurred, you use the simple past:

> I bought a new cell phone *last week*.
>
> I bought a new cell phone *at the mall*.

However, if you're simply stating a fact, most people would use the two interchangeably, and not consider either to be wrong (Though most grammarians would argue that the present perfect "have bought" is more correct.)

Which one you are likely to say is probably more about regional differences than anything else, especially when you add "I've bought a new cell phone" to the list. For some speakers, there's almost no practical difference in how they pronounce "I've" and "I" if they aren't speaking carefully.

There is one useful difference in meaning between them, though. If you want to emphasise that you *did* buy a new cell phone, or contradict someone who thinks you didn't, you would definitely choose "I **have bought** a new cell phone."

Answer (score 2):

> The present perfect is used to indicate a **link** between the present
>   and the past. The time of the action is before now but not specified,
>   and **we are often more interested in the result** than in the action
>   itself.

https://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-grammar/present-perfect/

Using this understanding the difference is:

- I have bought a new cell phone *and I still have it* - link to the present
- I bought a new cell phone *then I took it back to the shop for a refund* - the action *bought* is wholly and completely in the past with no link to the present.